# Encoding sounds to play in a Google Hangouts app with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, encoding, ffmpeg, google-api, google-plus

I have a Google Hangouts app and I am trying to let the user play a sound that I provide.

Google has this covered, with its Audio Resource, but it only accepts specifically encoded sound files, PCM 16 wav files.

I have been trying to encode my files using ffmpeg, but it does not seem to be working.
Any idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Here is my ffmpeg command line :
ffmpeg -i sound.mp3 -map_metadata -1 -flags bitexact sound.wav

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote hangout app that used audio and I noticed I had to use 44.1KHz sample rate on my 16 bit PCM WAV files or it wouldn't work.  See if you can add an option to change the sample rate to that.

Comment: That did not help much. I did change one thing though, now I load the sounds only when the user plays them. It makes it a bit more reliable but still not crazy. It seems to be a file size issue, but not clear yet.